# XML File Contains Only Blank Element Called ObjectProxy - C# XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have added XML Serialization into my project in order to store my object data in XML files.

I have used the following helper class to achieve this:

```cs
public static class SerializerHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="serializableObject"></param>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>

        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
            "SerializerHelper.cs");

        public static void SerializeObject<T>(string filepath, T serializableObject)
        {
            if (serializableObject == null) { return; }

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    xmlDocument.Load(stream);
                    xmlDocument.Save(filepath);
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
                logger.Error("Error Serializing: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes an xml file into an object list
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T DeSerializeObject<T>(string filepath)
        {
            T objectOut = default(T);

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath)) return objectOut;

            try
            {
                string attributeXml = string.Empty;

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(filepath);
                string xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml;

                using (StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    Type outType = typeof(T);

                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);
                    using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read))
                    {
                        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        reader.Close();
                    }

                    read.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception here
                logger.Error("Error Deserializing: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return objectOut;
        }
    }
```

Inside my methods, anywhere that I create/delete/alter objects, I use code such as the below to serialize the object data:

```cs
        //Increments the failed logon attempts counter
        public void incrementFailedLogonAttempts()
        {
            logonAttemptCounter.incrementFailedLogons();

            //Update the failed logon attempt counter in the XML Data Store
            SerializerHelper.SerializeObject(@"C:\Users\Michael"
            + @"\Google Drive\FDM Dev Course Content\Workspace\SystemAdmin\SystemAdmin\"
            + @"XML Data Store\LogonAttemptCounter.xml", logonAttemptCounter);
        }
```

However, after running all my unit tests, some of my XML files (which were serialized fine before running all tests) now look like this:

```cs
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ObjectProxy_4 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here? Or why it is going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I know actually. My tests use mock objects to mock dependencies. In many of my tests, I have created the object whose method is to be tested, injecting mock objects in the constructor. Is this what is causing the problem? I am serializing mock objects, which by definition are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know actually. My tests use mock objects to mock dependencies. In many of my tests, I have created the object whose method is to be tested, injecting mock objects in the constructor. Is this what is causing the problem? I am serializing mock objects, which by definition are empty?